# Token for state/province not displaying in email sent by the Drupal Rules module

Tags: webform-civicrm

Drupal 7.91

Webform 7.4.24

Webform CiviCRM Integration 7.x-5.8

Webform Rules 7.x-1.6

Rules 7.x-2.13

All the other tokens are working fine. For example,[data:civicrm_2_contact_1_address_city-value] displays the city for this same contact. However [data:values:civicrm_2_contact_1_address_state_province_id-value] does not return anything. I have tried all the other variations (like -raw) but none return anything.

Comment: Can you get the expected result from a plain webform email? Or in [submission:values] from a webform, just in case that's not the right token? It might help for troubleshooting to at least take rules out of the equation.

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the sugestion. Yes, it does return in a webform email: 
State/Province AL

Comment: Just in case it matters, one of your tokens above is data:values:civicrm... and the other is data:civicrm...

Comment: Wow... That did it. How did I miss that. Thanks!